# FastAPI hosted on Google cloud return 500 server error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I have a FastAPI API that takes an image, loads a Tensorflow model, and returns a prediction.
Locally everything is working fine, but I want to host it on Google Cloud I followed a tutorial and did the following:

1. created app.yaml file where the contents are

```yaml
runtime: python39    
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

2. requirements.txt having

```
fastapi
numpy
Pillow
pydantic
tensorflow
uvicorn
gunicorn
opencv-python
```

After that, I uploaded everything on Github, opened Google cloud, created a new project, activated cloud run and cloud build, cloned the git repo, and ran

```bash
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

I installed the requirements with

```bash
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

and finally launched the API using

```bash
gcloud app browse
```

What I get is either

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination" or "Error: Server Error
```

or

```
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Comment: Check the error logs (unicorn.error)

Comment: @CharlieV these are the errors that happened after the request
2022-06-27 22:07:58.749 EET
Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 305 MB after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
2022-06-27 22:07:58.749 EET
The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.

Comment: The error says everything about the problem....you need to increase the RAM as there is not enough in your instance

Comment: As stated by Isabi, this was generated because the instance ran out of memory.  Have you tried increasing the instance memory? Try [changing the instance class in your app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes), [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance), this will increase the memory limit according to the assigned class.

Comment: You can also use this stack answer to increase the [instance memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996861/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-memory-of-gcp-compute-instance-without-stopping-t)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I managed to solve the memory problem using app.yaml as Andres suggested, but I ran into another problem when I send a request I received 502 Bad Gateway and the logs say 
" [error] 16#16: *2 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "er-api-354613.lm.r.appspot.com"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Isabi, this was generated because the instance ran out of memory.  Have you tried increasing the instance memory? Try [changing the instance class in your app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes), [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance), this will increase the memory limit according to the assigned class.

You can also use this stack answer to increase the [instance memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996861/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-memory-of-gcp-compute-instance-without-stopping-t)